# Show a vector space is closed if the family is linearly independent

Tags: vector-spaces

I want to show that a set of vectors $K_i=\{\Sigma \alpha_iv_i : \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R_{+}} \} $ is closed if the vectors in $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ are linearly independent. I is an index set.

First of all, I am bit confused about the notion of closure in a vector space. Then, I'm not sure the best way to think about this question. Any direction would be very appreciated!

Comment: Given the form of the subset, my guess would be that they mean for you to consider this as the usual Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Your notation is not clear. What are you summing over?

Comment: Sorry! It has been updated

Comment: Is $I$ a finite index set? Closed means closed in the usual analysis sense.

Comment: Yes, I is a finite.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n \end{bmatrix}$, then
$K= \{ A x | x \ge 0 \}$, where $A$ is injective.

It is straightforward to establish that $\{x | x \ge 0 \}$ is closed. (Note that a set $C$ is closed **iff** whenever $c_i \in C$ and $c_i \to c$, then $c \in C$.)

Note that $K \subset {\cal R} A$ and note that ${\cal R} A$ is closed (key fact #1).

Note that if $k \in {\cal R} A$, then there is a unique $x$ such that $Ax = k$, in fact
$x = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T k$.
(The matrix $A^+$ is known as the Moore Penrose inverse.)
Furthermore, if $k \in {\cal R} A$, then $A A^+ k = k$ (key fact #2).

Suppose $k_i \in K$ and $k_i \to k$ (note that we must have $k \in {\cal R} A$), then we see that $x_i = A^+ k_i \to x = A^+ k$ by continuity. Since $x_i \ge 0$, we see that $x=A^+ k \ge 0$, and since $A x = A A^+ k = k$, we see that $k \in K$, hence $K$ is closed.

**Furthermore**...

Note that for **any** finite collection of $v_i$, not just linearly independent sets, the set $K=\{\sum_i \alpha_i v_i | \alpha_i \ge 0 \}$ is closed.

This is because if $k \in K$, we can always write $k$ as a positive combination of a linearly independent subset of the $v_i$ (Carathéodory's theorem) and
we can write $K$ as the union of finite number of cones generated by the linearly independent subsets of the $v_i$. (The union of a finite number of closed sets is closed.)